# Why function template does not understand NULL but works with nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function

```
int f(std::shared_ptr<MyClass> sptr);
```

After that I write the following template to be able to call it (and some other) functions:

```
template <typename Func, typename ArgType>
auto call(Func func, ArgType arg) -> decltype(func(arg))
{
    return func(arg);
}
```

Why do I get an error in the third line when I try to use this template with NULL?

```
auto r0 = f(0); // OK
auto r1 = call(f, nullptr); // OK
auto r2 = call(f, NULL); // ERROR! WHY??

1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>main.cpp(245): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type call(Func,Arg)'
1>          With the following template arguments:
1>          'Func=int (__cdecl *)(std::shared_ptr<MyClass>)'
1>          'Arg=int'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Does `f(NULL)` compile OK ?

Comment: @PaulR Yeah - see `r0` in his question.

Comment: @Barry: that's `f(0)` - I was asking about `f(NULL)` in case somehow `NULL` is defined as something other then `0`.

Comment: @PaulR f(0) or f(NULL) should be fine because 0 is special. But when type of 0 is deduce it is int, and from templated type it should be problematic. Rest OP can experiment and tell.

Comment: @MohitJain: thanks, yes I just read Joachim's explanation below - it's clear now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The clue is here:

```
Arg=int
```

`NULL` must be a null pointer constant which, before C++11, meant it must be an integer constant with value zero. In your implementation, it has type `int`, and is probably the literal `0`.

So the template parameter is deduced as `int`, which is not convertible to `shared_ptr`, hence the error.

As for the others:

```
auto r0 = f(0); // OK
```

The literal `0` can be treated as a null pointer constant, and converted to `shared_ptr`, if passed directly to the function. Within the `call`, the argument isn't a literal, but a variable of type `int`, which can't be converted.

```
auto r1 = call(f, nullptr); // OK
```

`nullptr` has its own type, which is convertible to `shared_ptr`.

Comment: but why this works: f(0) ? I mean why conversion works in the first line and doesn't work in the 3-rd? shared_ptr can be constructed from 0 in the first case and can't in the third.

Answer (score 3):

Because in C++ `NULL` is usually defined as `0` which is an `int`. So the template type `ArgType` is deduced to be an `int` and you can't convert an `int` to a `std::shared_ptr`.

Note that it works for e.g. `f(0)` (and should then work for `f(NULL)`) but that's because the compiler knows that `0` in that case is a null-pointer. In the `call` function, the compiler have no idea what value the variable `arg` will have, only that it's of type `int` which can't be converted implicitly to a pointer.

Comment: Yes, `f(0);` would be fine. But `int i = 0; f(i);` would be an error.